# How to efficiently work with GetProperties()?

Tags: c#

```
public object GetObjectToSerialize(object value, Type targetType)
{
      var allProperties = value.GetType().GetProperties();

      var passwordProperties = allProperties.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                                            .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Password"))
                                            .ToList();

      var passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute = passwordProperties
                .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any());

       if (passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute.Any())
       {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(SafeFormatter.Format(BackgroundJobsLocalization.Culture, BackgroundJobsLocalization.PasswordWithoutEncryptedAttribute));
       }

       foreach (var property in passwordProperties)
       {
            property.SetValue(value, null, null);
       }

        return value;
 }
```

I use this method quite often. How can I optimize it? Because as I known `value.GetType().GetProperties();` works recursively (for base object, then for base object properties , then each property of base object properties, etc)

Comment: why don't you add the serializer attributes?

Comment: Why do I need to add it?

Comment: You know that you are setting to `null` the value of the `Password` properties in the `foreach`, right?

Comment: @xanatos yes, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) its result. Save the result in a `Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>`, then in the beginning of the function check if you have already calculated it. If yes, return the value of the `Dictionary<,>`. If you want to make it thread-safe, use a `ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>`.

Something like:

```
//private static readonly Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> PasswordProperties = new Dictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();
private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> PasswordProperties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]>();

public static object GetObjectToSerialize(object value, Type targetType) {
    Type type = value.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties;

    if (!PasswordProperties.TryGetValue(type, out properties)) 
    {
        properties = type.GetProperties()
                         .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                         .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Password"))
                         .ToArray();

        var passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute = properties
                    .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any());

        if (passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute.Any()) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(); // SafeFormatter.Format(BackgroundJobsLocalization.Culture, BackgroundJobsLocalization.PasswordWithoutEncryptedAttribute));
        }

        PasswordProperties[type] = properties;
    }

    foreach (var property in properties) 
    {
        property.SetValue(value, null, null);
    }

    return value;
}
```

If you have access to the type of `value` at compile time, it is optimizable in another way, by memoizing inside a field of a static generic class:

```
public static class ObjectHelper
{
    public static T GetObjectToSerialize<T>(T value) 
    {
        foreach (var property in ObjectHelperInner<T>.Properties) 
        {
            property.SetValue(value, null, null);
        }

        return value;
    }

    private static class ObjectHelperInner<T>
    {
        public static readonly PropertyInfo[] Properties;

        static ObjectHelperInner()
        {
            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                                                    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Password"))
                                                    .ToArray();

            var passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute = properties
                        .Where(p => !p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EncryptedConfigurationItemAttribute), false).Any());

            if (passwordWithoutEncryptedAttribute.Any()) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(); // SafeFormatter.Format(BackgroundJobsLocalization.Culture, BackgroundJobsLocalization.PasswordWithoutEncryptedAttribute));
            }

            Properties = properties;
        }
    }
}
```

This second version of the code **won't** work if you have:

```
object obj = something;
ObjectHelper.GetObjectToSerialize(obj);
```

It will only work if you have:

```
SomeConcreteType obj = something;
ObjectHelper.GetObjectToSerialize(obj);
```

Another possible solution is to generate (through `Expression` trees) some code at runtime to clean an object. It becomes much faster, but the code generation becomes much slower. And the code to do it is much more complex.